# Extension of a semisimple Lie algebra with a semisimple Lie algebra is semisimple. Why?

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I am looking for a proof, that the extension of a semisimple Lie algebra with a semisimple is again semisimple.

I know the Theorem of Weyl and the one of Levi, so I thought about maybe using them.

Comment: Hint: The extension will in fact just be a direct sum.

Comment: I see the direkt sum of vectorspaces, because of the Theorem of levi, but I don't know why it should be a direct sum of lie algebras.

Comment: Consider the Lie algebra as a module over the semisimple ideal that it extends.

Comment: I tried that many times including using weyl's theorem and different combinations which algebra is a module over which, but didn't got it.

Comment: Let $L$ be a Lie algebra with an ideal $I$ such that $I$ and $L/I$ are both semisimple. Now $L$ is a module over $I$ so it is completely reducible, and clearly $I$ is a submodule. Write $L = I \oplus J$ for some submodule $J$. What can you say about $J$?

Comment: $J$ is a $I$ submodule and as $I$ was an Ideal, so we get $[J,I]=0$, what looks good. But why should $J$ be a subalgebra?

Comment: Can nobody help me?

Comment: I realized that it is actually easier to prove the semisimplicity directly from the definition, only using the standard properties of Lie algebras. If nobody else does so, I will give some detailed hints for this later when I am on a proper computer.

Comment: Here are some proper hints: Let $L$ be the Lie algwebra with a semisimple ideal $I$ such that $L/I$ is semisimple. Let $S$ be a solvable ideal of $L$. Show that $S = 0$ by doing the following: First, show that $S\subseteq I$ by considering $(S+I)/I$ in $L/I$. Then show that this means that $S = 0$.

Comment: Oh my god, it's that trivial? Shame one me. Using , that the image of a solvable ideal under a surjective Liealgebra-homomorphism is a solvable ideal and that  Lie algebra is solvable iff it's solvable Radical is zero made this task very easy... Thanks a lot, you saved my night.

Comment: To make this question not appear unanswered, I would recommend you put up your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

In order for this question not to stay on the list of unanswered, here is the full answer:

Assume $L$ is a Lie algebra with a semisimple ideal $I$ such that $L/I$ is semisimple. Assume $S$ is a solvable ideal of $L$.

The ideal $(S + I)/I$ in $L/I$ is isomorphic to $S/(S\cap I)$ and thus solvable. But since $L/I$ is semisimple, this means that it must be $0$, which means that $S + I = I$ so $S\subseteq I$.

But now $S$ is a solvable ideal in the semisimple Lie algebra $I$, so we must have $S = 0$ which completes the proof.